# React Native - Variable link using a prop

Tags: react-native, api, react-props

I'm making an app with some products that I got from my Wordpress database. On the homescreen, I have an overview of all the products, each in a tile. I want to be able to put a button in each tile, which links to the specific product page. But, since it works with a component, I need to be able to do this with a prop. And, if possible, based on the title of the API.

This is my code for the screen with all the products:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
 
import SuitcaseItem from '../components/SuitcaseItem';
 
const AllSuitcasesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
 
  const [suitcases, setSuitcases] = useState([]);
 
  const getSuitcases = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=59", {
 
        }
      )
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      setSuitcases(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
 
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getSuitcases();
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>

          <View style={styles.flexbox2}>
            <Text style={styles.products}>Onze koffers</Text>
            <View style={styles.shoppingcart}>
              <Image
                  style={styles.icon}
                  source={{uri: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1413/1413908.png'}}
                />
              <Text style={styles.number}>0</Text>
            </View>
          </View>


        <View style={styles.list}>

        <FlatList
        data={suitcases}
 
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <SuitcaseItem
          title={item.title.rendered}
          imageUri={{uri: 'https://www.samsonite.be/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dw851ab6f0/images/misc/sams_share-image.jpg'}}
          desc={item.slug}
          buttonText={item.title.rendered}
          />
        )}
      />
      
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default AllSuitcasesScreen;
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Now, when I click the black button, I go to the page 'Evo L', which I also made. This is the button that I use:

```
<Pressable style={styles.seeProduct} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Evo L")}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Bekijk product: {props.buttonText}</Text>
        </Pressable>
```

This is in another file, the 'SuitcaseItem'.

So, I should be able to put something like `navigation.navigate("props.buttonNav")` with `buttonNav = {item.title.rendered}` so it goes to the page Evo L if I click on that one and then Evo M when I click on that tile and so one. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to a screen. [See this excellent official documentation for React Navigation on passing props.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

-> Make a generic item detail screen like ItemDetail (instead of Evo L).

-> Modify the `navigation.navigate("props.buttonNav")` to:

```
navigation.navigate("ItemDetail", {itemTitle: props.buttonText})
```

You can access these props in the ItemDetail screen as:

```
function ItemDetail({ navigation, route }) {
    return(
        <Text>route.params.itemTitle</Text> 
    )         
}
```